# Vaadin 7 - instant download of dynamically created file

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

My scenario is: using **Vaadin 7.7.10**, I have on click generated file, that I want to download once it is generated.

I have generator method, that returns `byte[]` (could be also easily modified to any `OutputStream` if needed), then I create `StreamResource` from it. So I have the resource ready to be downloaded, but now what?

I believe can't use approach with `FileDownloader`, because there I would have to generate the file every time the page is displayed prior to actual click on extended button (and I don't want to do that, as it is quite expensive operation which will shall only be used on demand).

I was able to achieve the desired effect using `Page.getCurrent().open(streamResource, null, false)`, but `.open` with `Resource` argument is deprecated since Vaadin 7, so I don't wanna rely on it...

Is there any workaround or another approach to this?

Comment: Why can't you generate the file on click with the FileDownloader? _I think_, if you make a custom class that implements StreamSource. You can override the getStream method and do your file generation in there?

Comment: Look at this thread: https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/2864064

Comment: You are right, Jay. I was confused because I put StreamSource custom class inside onClick event, so I was like "hey, this occurs only after click, but I need it for extending FileDownloader before the actual click". What I needed to do was to put the generation code inside constructor and then just extend the FileDownloader. Then it works correctly "on demand".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vaadin `FileDownloader` might be still capable to handle this with some customization. However I once created a reporting system with a different approach. The idea is to use component `BrowserFrame` that takes `StreamResource` as its constructor param.

File generation is started - for example - by clicking a button. When generation finalizes it results in to a `byte[]`. From `byte[]` is created a `StreamSource` which then is used to create `StreamResouce` which is then used as contents of `BrowserFrame`.

Finally this `BrowserFrame` is added to the ui somewhere which causes browser to react.

In my case there was a need to generate parameterized PDF reports which user could first preview and then download if in need. I had a PDF generator that provided the `byte[]`. Browser recognized type from file name extension `.pdf` and opened PDF plugin for preview & download.

You can put any binary stuff to `byte[]` used to construct `BrowserFrame` and set appropriate file name extension.

You can also have some `Layout` in your ui that - for example - has a progress indicator while file is generating in the background and in to which the `BrowserFrame` component is attached when file is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not an ideal approach, but we can initialize the file downloader with a dummy resource at first

```
 new FileDownloader(
        new StreamResource(
            new StreamSource() {
              @Override
              public InputStream getStream() {
                return null;
              }},""));
```

and later set it to a new resource inside a listener event.

```
fileDownoader.setFileDownloadResource(newResource)
```