# How to open a PDF file in pdf reader with vaadin?

Tags: pdf, vaadin, pdf-reader

A new Programmer here.

I was searching about open a PDF file with vaading. I can open it in the browser or download it without problem, but i need to open in a tab of my application, or at least open it in the predefined pdf reader and the Desktop class is not an option.

Can anyone help me? I only saw browser options, and now i was in war with the WT PDF Viewer class trying it.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: If you PDF is already available as downloadable file under some URL of your web application, then you can simply add an `Anchor` (Vaadin Flow) or `Link` (Vaadin 8) component to your UI that points to that URL. The browser will open a PDF viewer automatically.

Comment: hi! thank you for your response, but it is not for an URL is a temporal file that i create from jasper with the code.

JasperPrint jrprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameters, beanCollection);
      ByteArrayOutputStream byteArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jrprint, byteArray);

Comment: If you are using Vaadin 8, one possibility is to use Embedded since accepts Resource as parameter see API here https://vaadin.com/api/framework/8.6.0/com/vaadin/ui/Embedded.html and Resource here https://vaadin.com/api/framework/8.6.0/com/vaadin/server/Resource.html You probably would use StreamResource.

Comment: sorry for not been expecific enough, is vaadin 7

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47282174) question, it should be possible to use StreamResource also in Vaadin 7. There should be further documentation somewhere on the net. Vaadin 7 is old though.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Vaadin 7 & 8, one possibility is to use Embedded since accepts Resource as parameter see API for Vaadin 8 here https://vaadin.com/api/framework/8.6.0/com/vaadin/ui/Embedded.html and Resource here https://vaadin.com/api/framework/8.6.0/com/vaadin/server/Resource.html You probably would use StreamResource .